# Loop through directory, delete

Tags: python

I would like to loop through the given directory `e://www/files/delivery` and all its subdirectories and delete all images that end with `_thumb.jpg`.

What i have tried so far:

```
import os

dir='e:\www\files\delivery'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
  for name in files:
    if name.endswith(("_thumb.jpg")):
      os.remove(name?)....
```

Apparently this does not work.

Also, if i alternatively want to resize all images using `python wand library` instead of deleting them, would it be the same process?

Comment: If you just glance at the [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) documentation, both examples show you how to get the pathname. (The second one is even passing it to `os.remove`.)

Comment: This isn't actually going to get to your loop, because `e:\www\files\delivery` has a form-feed character in the middle of it, not a backslash and an f. _Always_ use raw strings, escape your backslashes, or use forward slashes instead when dealing with Windows paths.

Comment: Building on what @abarnert says, in case you don'y know what a raw string is or how to make it...  A raw string does not do any interpretation of the characters (i.e. `\n` would stay as `\n` and not become a new line).  To make a raw string, put an `r` before the string: `r'e:\www\files\delivery'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import os

dir='e:\www\files\delivery'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
  for name in files:
    if name.endswith(("_thumb.jpg")):
      os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Comment: `join(root, dir, name)` is wrong; just use `join(root, name)`. (Think about it: you're sticking `e:\www\files\delivery` in the middle of his path.)